# Installing Jekyll on Elementary OS using gem

Tags: software-installation, ruby, gem

When I try to install Jekyll on Elementary OS Luna with the command `sudo gem install jekyll --no-rdoc --no-ri` I get the following error.

```
 -- rbconfig (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:29
from /usr/bin/gem:8:in `require'
from /usr/bin/gem:8
```

Can anybody help me make sense of the error and maybe suggest a fix?

Comment: What version of gem are you using? From where? I tried reproducing the problem with `gem install --user-install jekyll --no-rdoc --no-ri` and was without a hitch on Debian Testing, gem version 2.2.2.

Comment: I think your issue is that you're using a fairly old version of Ruby, v1.8. I'd upgrade that and try again. Myself and Braiam have both tried this using Ruby (2.1.1 in my case) and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't run `/bin/bash --login` before I installed Jekyll

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution but could you please expand on it a little? Show the exact commands needed to fix this?

Comment: are you using `rvm`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to a newer version of Ruby. I tried building the Jekyll gem on 1.9 and it failed here:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    listen requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

However when I installed it on this version:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.1p7 (2014-01-15 revision 44603) [x86_64-linux]
```

It installed just fine.